# How to build a 404 page with react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I just upgraded to v6beta for react-router-dom because I wanted to organize my routes, but the 404 page is now broken:

```
export function AllRoutes(props) {

  return(
    <Routes>

      <Route path="/about-us">
        <Route path="contact">     <AboutContact/> </Route>
        <Route path="our-logo">    <AboutLogo/>    </Route>
        <Route path="the-mission"> <AboutMission/> </Route>
        <Route path="the-team">    <AboutTeam/>    </Route>
        <Route path="our-work">    <AboutWork/>    </Route>
      </Route>

      <Route path="/user">
        <Route path="sign-in"> <UserSignIn/> </Route>
        <Route path="sign-up"> <UserSignUp/> </Route>
      </Route>


      <Route path="/">
        <Home/>
      </Route>

      <Route >
        <NotFound/>
      </Route>

    </Routes>
  )
}
```

So everything works as expected (including the home page) except the not found page, which does not work even when adding `path="/*"` or `path="*"`

Any easy solution for this?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

```
<Routes>

  // Use it in this way, and it should work:
  <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />

  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
  <Route path="/settings" element={<Settings />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: Making the asterisk '*' route as the first route, you are hiding all other routes, hence all requests will go through the NotFound page. you must make it the last route.

Comment: @AhmedHany. no, This will happen if you are using the old versions. now " > v6 " they changed the way it works. it's a lot better now.

Comment: @Haitham6373 so what's better to have it on top instead of bottom? what's the diff in v6?

Comment: @Haitham6373 It doesn't work if I navigate to `<baseUrl>/someRandomText/`. Note the trailing slash.

Comment: Is this supposed to work with nested routes also?

Comment: But it still returns status code 200, how to return 404 status?

Comment: Not directly related to the question at hand, but IMO ya'll are playing with fire w/o having `sensitive={false}` set in the `<Route>`. (`<Route path="/Home" sensitive={false} element={<Home />} />`.

Answer (score 30):

React Router v6 does not use exact attribute to match the exact routes. By default it matches the exact route. To match any value use "*" in the route path.

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
    </div>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>    enter code here
```

Comment: how do you handle nested route?

Answer (score 12):

react router v6 don't have Switch
so you need to declare path='*'

```
<BrowserRouter> 
  <Routes> 
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
    <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact/>} />
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound/>} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use

```
<Route path="*" element={ <Navigate to="/404" replace />} />
```

this way you have a redirection and a url replacement

for example :

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes , Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from '../../pages/Home'
import Account from '../../pages/Account'
import Contact from '../../pages/Contact'
import NotFound  from '../../pages/NotFound'


const AllRoutes= () => {
    return(
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={ <Home /> } />
                <Route path="/Account" element={ <Account /> } />
                <Route path="/Contact" element={ <Contact /> } />
                <Route path="/404" element={ <NotFound /> } />
                <Route path="*" element={ <Navigate to="/404" replace />} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default AllRoutes
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to render a Route with a path of `*`, and React Router will make sure to only render it if none of the other Routes match.

If your 404 component name is `PageNotFound`:

> <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound/>} />

1 [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/route-objects?file=src/App.tsx) link (its implementation is a little bit different)

2 [The easiest example is here](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_router.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Create component and inside component create function NotFound.

in app.js create  and give path="*" and element should be NotFound function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).