# 404 page not found not working react-router v6 (using more than one param)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, dynamic-routing

My shallow understanding is causing a simple issue with rendering the NotFound page...

```
<Routes>
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />}/>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/:category/:id" element={<Article />} />
        </Routes>
```

When the uri contains one "/", it renders the matching component or NotFound component, however, when the uri includes two "/", for example "/asoejdnxx/acnoiw" which doesn't exist, it doesn't route to the NotFound page but just renders a blank page with no errors.

I'm assuming the issue is because react is looking for the params in the thirds Route(which has the :category and :id param) regardless of it matching or not.

I'm sure there should be no need to add a condition in the "Article" component, such as if the param doesn't match to an existing :id, render something else(since thats the purpose of path="*"), but i cant find a way to redirect or render the NotFound component.

Comment: What makes you think that `"/asoejdnxx/acnoiw"` wouldn't be matched by `path="/:category/:id"` and render the "404" route and `NotFound` component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build a 404 page with react-router-dom v6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67050966/how-to-build-a-404-page-with-react-router-dom-v6)

Comment: @DrewReese I may be using the incorrect terminology but the "asoejdnxx" and "acnoiw" params don't exist. they're both made up strings that don't match any params

Comment: Right, and how would the route component know what are valid strings? It takes a URL path and parses it and finds a matching path string. In any case, the routed component still needs to handle validating the params it receives. I've provided an answer below with example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What makes you think that `"/asoejdnxx/acnoiw"` wouldn't be matched by `path="/:category/:id"` and render the "404" route and `NotFound` component instead?

For URL path `"/asoejdnxx/acnoiw"` the `path="/:category/:id"` will match it and render the `Article` component. It's at this point that `Article` needs to validate the route params it's consuming and if they are invalid, redirect to the 404 route.

I suggest actually creating a 404 route that you can redirect to.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/:category/:id" element={<Article />} />
  <Route path="notfound" element={<NotFound />} />
  <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/notfound" replace />} />
</Routes>
```

In the `Article` component use a `useEffect` hook to redirect to `"/notfound"` under the correct circumstances.

Example:

```
const { category, id } = useParams();
const navigate = useNavigate();

...

useEffect(() => {
  if (/* invalid route params */) {
    navigate("/notfound", { replace: true });
  }
}, [category, id, navigate]);
```

Comment: Thanks Drew i now understand how it works. i initially thought path="*" without any circumstances would do the work.

Comment: hey Drew hate to bother you but how can i validate my params? 
```js
const {category, id} = useParams();
console.log(!category)
console.log(!id)
```
i'm sure i shouldn't be taking an approach like that. Both params are strings FYI

Comment: got it working using Object.keys() .

Answer (score 1):

You can manually redirect the user to the 404 page:

````js
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const YourComponent = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    if(/*some condition*/){
        navigate("/404");
    }
    return /*...*/
}```
````